# Apple Mach-O Linker Error_

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I have a Swift project (Xcode 9.1, macOS 10.13), and I tried to link my own C-library with the ViewController.swift by doing bridging header for C file with Swift.

[image: Screen of my project]

However, the comilation error was occured, and this is output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_HTS_Engine_clear", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_clear in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_clear)
  "_ffeature_string", referenced from:
      _create_label in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_phoneme in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_word in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_val_string_n", referenced from:
      _create_label in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_initialize", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_initialize in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_initialize)
  "_HTS_Engine_set_speed", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_speed in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_speed)
  "_register_cmu_us_kal", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_relation_head", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_label_data in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_item_next", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _create_label in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_label_data in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_utt_relation", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_label_data in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_refresh", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_set_volume", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_volume in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_volume)
  "_delete_utterance", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_clear in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_unregister_cmu_us_kal", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_clear in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_save_riff", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_flite_synth_text", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_analysis in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_set_msd_threshold", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_msd_threshold in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_msd_threshold)
  "_HTS_Engine_set_beta", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_beta in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_beta)
  "_HTS_Engine_add_half_tone", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_add_half_tone in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_add_half_tone)
  "_val_string", referenced from:
      _create_label in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_set_alpha", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_alpha in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_alpha)
  "_HTS_Engine_set_gv_weight", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_gv_weight in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_gv_weight)
  "_HTS_Engine_synthesize_from_strings", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_synthesize in flite_hts_engine.o
  "_HTS_Engine_set_sampling_frequency", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_sampling_frequency in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_sampling_frequency)
  "_HTS_Engine_set_fperiod", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_fperiod in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_fperiod)
  "_ffeature_int", referenced from:
      _create_label in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_nphoneme_in_syllable in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_nsyllable_in_word in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_nword_in_phrase in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_nphrase_in_utterance in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_accent in flite_hts_engine.o
      _Flite_Text_Analyzer_get_stress in flite_hts_engine.o
      ...
  "_HTS_Engine_load", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_load in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_load)
  "_HTS_Engine_set_audio_buff_size", referenced from:
      _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_audio_buff_size in flite_hts_engine.o
     (maybe you meant: _Flite_HTS_Engine_set_audio_buff_size)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I tried to delete all files on DerivedData, also cleaning in the same my project (by Product/Clean) but the problem not changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a compilation error.  It's a linker error: the Swift and your C code was compiled just fine, but then the compiled code from some other library was not found, so all the pieces could not be linked together.

Guessing from your pictures, I'm assuming that you wrote a C wrapper, in files `flite_hts_engine.c` and `flite_hts_engine.h`, around some other C code in `htsEngineLib`.  For example, `_Flite_HTS_Engine_initialize` might be in the wrapper and tries to use `_HTS_Engine_initialize` in the library, but that (compiled) code is not available, or maybe the available code is for a wrong architecture.

Resolution of this problem depends on the details such as whether you have the source code for `htsEngineLib`.  If you do, an easy solution might be to just make it part of your project.  If you only have a compiled library, then you have to ensure the library is for the right architecture.  For example, if you have a compiled library provided for the iPhone, you cannot use it to build an app for macOS or iPhone simulator.

Comment: After I added source file (by drag and drop way) for all libraries in hts_engineLib, the linker errors was disappeared, then they appears 6 compilation errors, I correct them but after that they happen 66 linker errors. I tried to add the object file (.o) for all source files but the error still happens. maybe because the C warpper, How to write a C wrapper in .c and .h files?

Comment: What were the typical compilation and linker errors?  How did you fix the compilation problems?  Did you add .o files to the project? That should never be done, they aren't source code.  Why did you try to create a wrapper around htsEngineLib in the first place?  To simplify the interface, or is the lib in C++?  There is a lot of info on SO and web in general about writing wrappers.